# Solving n linear equation

Tags: c, algorithm, math, linear-equation

I am trying to solve *n* linear equations with *n* variables. I used cramer's rule but in cases it failed when determinant is equal to zero. How to approach this problem ?

I am using **c** language.

Also my linear equation is of form:

for `n = 3`:

```
- x + y + z = a
  x - y + z = b
  x + y - z = c
```

for `n = 2`:

```
- x + y = a
  x - y = b
```

I am unable to proceed further.

Answer (score 1):

when solving with cramer, if the determinant is zero you have two cases:

- **at least one variable has a non zero - determinant**: there is no solution
- **the determinant for all variables is zero**: then you have an infinite number of solutions.

  in the last case, you can find an answer in terms of one of the variables.

Answer (score 0):

In `Ax = b`, when the determinant of `A` is equal to zero there is no unique solution. In particular, if `b` is 0 there are infinitely many solutions. It's also possible that no solution exists.

Your options are:

- flagging this as an error
- returning the `x` that minimizes the difference between `Ax` and `b`

Comment: The fact that `b!=0` does not guarantee that no solution exists.  E.g., in the second example from the OP, there are infinite solutions provided that `a=-b`.

Comment: True; I wasn't thinking.

Answer (score 0):

If the determinant is equal to zero, then the system is degenerate, meaning that there are either no solutions or an infinite number of solutions.  Consider your second example:

```
-x+y=a
x-y=b
```

We can rewrite this as

```
x-y=-a
x-y=b
```

So either `b=-a`, in which case any pair `(x,x-b)` is a solution, or else `b!=-a` in which case there are no solutions.